# turning a list of list of 1 string into a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of one string that looks like this:

```
['(0.027725, 0.0088202301), (0.00055000000000000003, 0.0040760101), 
  (0.1666, 0.0020067799), (0.00545, 0.021263899)']
```

But I want it to be a list of tuples that look that this:

```
[(0.027725, 0.0088202301),
 (0.00055000000000000003, 0.0040760101),
 (0.1666, 0.0020067799),
 (0.00545, 0.021263899)]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` with some string manipulation, but how did this string come to be? It sounds like you should fix *that* issue if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = ['(0.027725, 0.0088202301), (0.00055000000000000003, 0.0040760101), (0.1666, 0.0020067799), (0.00545, 0.021263899)']
new_s = ast.literal_eval('[{}]'.format(s[0]))
```

Output:

```
[(0.027725, 0.0088202301), (0.00055, 0.0040760101), (0.1666, 0.0020067799), (0.00545, 0.021263899)]
```